# How to balance chemical equations with polyatomic ions

Tags: ionic-compounds, elements

I know that you can not split poly-atomic ions but I am confused on how to balance the following equation:

9PbSO4 -> 10PBSO3 + 3O2

Pb = 9    Pb = 10
S = 9     S = 10
O = 36    O = 36

Obviously the equation is not balanced and there is an oxygen outside of a poly-atomic ion which makes it harder to balance. Do I count the oxygen with the oxygen in SO?

What numbers could I use to get PB and S the same on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the original unbalanced equation $\ce{PbSO4 -> PbSO3 + O2}.$

$\ce{PbSO3}$ needs only one more oxygen atom to balance $\ce{PbSO4}$; one atom of oxygen is $\frac{1}{2}\ce{O2}$.

This balances, then, as $\ce{PbSO4 -> PbSO3 + 1/2 O2}$.

Since half molecules are not permitted, double everything to:

$\ce{2 PbSO4 -> 2 PbSO3 + O2}$

Comment: I edited your equations. Have a look at http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know/3046#3046 for details.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Given that you have a lot of experience in teaching chemistry, you might find the current [discussion on homework questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/a-new-policy-of-closure-november-2016) interesting.